# Ejecutar Hook de WordPress desde Javascript

Tags: wordpress, random

Saludos Amigos, Tengo el siguiente Hook de WP :

```
add_action('template_redirect','random_template');
    function random_template() {
        $posts = get_posts('post_type=post&orderby=rand&numberposts=1');
           foreach($posts as $post) {
             $link = get_permalink($post);
    }
    wp_redirect($link,307);
    exit;
}
```

Y tengo el siguiente código de Javascript

```
    $('#Animacion').on("ended", function () {        
        // This does the ajax request
        alert("FIN animacion");
        $.ajax({
                url: "http://url.sitio",
                success: function( data ) {

                }
        })
});
```

Necesito que cuando una animación que ejecuto desde JS al finalizar ejecute la función que tengo en WordPress que es un random de link, no sé como hacer que se conecten estas dos funciones.

Agradezco una guía.

Answer (score 2):

**Solución :**

Gracias a [Juan](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/32716/juan) comparto el código para la comunidad :

Random Link (Post) --> functions.php

```
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'variables_php_js');
  // Función de puesta en cola
  function variables_php_js(){
  global $link;
     $args = new WP_Query(array(
         'posts_per_page'       => '1',
         'no_found_rows'        => true,
         'orderby'              => 'rand',
         'ignore_sticky_posts'  => true,
     ));

     if ( $args->have_posts() ) :
       while ( $args->have_posts() ) : $args->the_post();
         $link = get_permalink(); 
       endwhile;
     endif; wp_reset_query();

    wp_enqueue_script( 'variables-php-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
  wp_localize_script( 'variables-php-js', 'link',array('url' => $link,));
 }
```

Y El código para el archivo scripts.js :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#Animacion').on("ended", function () {
     location.href = link.url;
     }); 
});
```

Al ejecutarse una animación inicial me permite que redireccione de forma aleatoria a cualquier post en WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

Las funciones de Wordpress están en PHP y se ejecutan mucho antes de que comience a ejecutarse el javascript.

Osea, no podes llamar funciones de wordpress desde javascript.

Lo que podes hacer es ejecutar la función:

```
function random_template() {
        $posts = get_posts('post_type=post&orderby=rand&numberposts=1');
           foreach($posts as $post) {
             $link = get_permalink($post);
    }
```

de antemando en el wordpress, para conseguir el link al que queres redirigir y bajarlo al javascript de la página usando [wp_localize_script()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) para tenerlo disponible en una variable (array).

Después en el `on "end"` de la animación rederigirs al link pero desde javascript agregando un `location.href = <valor del link en el array javascript bajado desde el wordpress>`

Comment: Gracias Juan, tu guia fue de mucha ayuda y aprendí algo nuevo en WP.